# Maven artifact version naming convention

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is this a valid maven artifact version in my pom?

```
<version>1.0-MyBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

or is it that the artifact version should contain only numbers like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: If you are working with Maven 3 yes it's valid.

Comment: Yes, it is Maven 3. Thanks much. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven 3, as per [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855), it is valid to use something like `<version>1.0-MyBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>`